# how to set limit of camera position in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, frontend

I want to set the limitation of the camera position in my `threejs` scene and I don't know how to do that. For example, when I'm using `OrbitControls` and zoom out, the camera zoom in and zoom out doesn't have any limit. I want the camera to stop when `camera.position.z = 5` and stop again when camera zoom out is about `camera.position.z = 10`. I want to set the `camera.position.z` between these positions. Look at the camera limit on this site model: https://threejs-journey.com/

I tried this:

```
if (camera.position.z =< 5) {
    camera.position.z = 5;
}
else if (camera.position.z >=10)
{
    camera.position.z = 10;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please look at [the docs for `OrbitControl`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls), particularly the `min___` and `max___` properties, which can be set to limit the motion of the camera.

Comment: this limit is just for camera appearance , it's not for set limit of position.z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set limits to the zoom levels, you can use [`OrbitControls.maxDistance`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=orbit#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.maxDistance) and `.minDistance`. By default, these values are infinity and zero, respectively, so that’s why you’re not hitting any limit when zooming out.

```js
controls.maxDistance = 20;
controls.minDistance = 3;
```

Comment: thanks for your help , i put this code after ( let controls = new OrbitControls(camera,canvas);controls.maxZoom = 20;controls.minZoom = 3; ) but it doens't work yet

Comment: i found the solution , that's it : 

controls.minDistance = 2
controls.maxDistance = 5

thank you Stack overflow and marquizzo